# Stemming a text file to remove suffixes given linewise in another file using sed

Tags: bash, sed, stemming, suffix

I have one file `suffix.txt` which contains some strings linewise, for example-

```
ing
ness
es
ed
tion
```

Also, I have a text file `text.txt` which contains some text,
it is given that `text.txt` consists only of lowercase letters and without any punctuation, for example-

```
the raining cloud answered the man all his interrogation and with all
questioned mind the princess responded
harness all goodness without getting irritated
```

I want to remove the suffixes from the original words in `text.txt` only once for every suffix. Thus I expect the following output-

```
the rain cloud answer the man all his interroga and with all
question mind the princess respond
har all good without gett irritat
```

Note that `tion` was not removed from `questioned` since the original word didn't contain `tion` as a suffix. It would be really helpful if someone could answer this with `sed` commands.
I was using a naive script that doesn't seem to do the job-

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p; do
  sed -i "s/$p / /g" text.txt;
  sed -i "s/$p$//g" text.txt;
done <suffix.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                   # generate a regex of suffices
    s=s (s==""?"(":"|") $0  # (ing|ness|es|ed|tion)$
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    s=s ")$"                # well, above )$ is inserted here
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)      # iterate all the words and
        sub(s,"",$i)        # apply regex to each of them
}1' suffix text             # output
```

Output:

```
the rain cloud answer the man all his interroga and with all
question mind the princess respond
har all good without gett irritat
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hairy but sed and unix tools only:

```
sed -E -f <(tr '\n' '|' <suffix.txt | sed 's/\|$//; s/\|/\\\\b|/g; s/$/\\\\b/' | xargs printf 's/%s//g') text.txt
```

The

```
tr '\n' '|' <suffix.txt | sed 's/\|$//; s/\|/\\\\b|/g; s/$/\\\\b/' | xargs printf 's/%s//g'
```

generates the substitution script of

```
s/ing\b|ness\b|es\b|ed\b|tion\b//g
```

This requires GNU sed for `\b`.

It would be *easier* with perl, ruby, awk, etc

Here is a GNU awk:

```
gawk -i join 'FNR==NR {arr[FNR]=$1; next}
FNR==1{re=join(arr,1,length(arr),"\\>|"); re=re "\\>"}
{gsub(re,"")}
1
' suffix.txt text.txt
```

Both produce:

```
the rain cloud answer the man all his interroga and with all
question mind the princess respond
har all good without gett irritat
```

Comment: Acually this doesn't gives the desired output.

Comment: You likely are not using GNU sed.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 'y/\n/|/;s/|$//;s#.*#s/\\B(&)\\b//g#' suffixFile | sed -Ef - textFile
```

Convert suffixFile into sed commands in a file and pass that via a pipe to a second invocation of sed that amends the textFile.

N.B. The sed command use the `\B` and `\b` to match a suffix.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but can you please explain some bits of your code?